# PyTorch: Why I can't detect CUDA on windows?

Tags: pytorch, torch

I have GPU (`NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070`) with the following versions:

```
windows 10 Enterprise
python 3.8.10
torch 1.11.0
```

`nvcc -V` gives:

> Cuda Compliation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58

`nvidia-smi` gives:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 465.89 Driver Version: 465.89 CUDA Version 11.3
```

When running the following code:

```
import torch
print (torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I'm getting `False`

What do I need to configure in order to use GPU (under windows) ?